# Thread pool running sequentially?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a function that gets all the files in a directory, but does it in parallel by adding each sub-directory to the thread pool. I thought this would mean that each directory would be traversed in parallel and since there are many sub directories, it would get done much faster than doing it sequentially. My code is as follows:

```
    private object addlock = new object();
    private void addFiles(string[] newFiles)
    {
        lock (addlock) {
            files.AddRange( newFiles );
            Console.WriteLine( "Added {0} files", newFiles.Length );
        }
    }

    private void getFilesParallel(string dir)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists( dir )) {
            return;
        }

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories( dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly );
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent( false );

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (object obj) =>
        {
            addFiles( Directory.GetFiles( dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly ) );
            mre.Set();
        } );

        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        long memorySize = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;

        Console.WriteLine( "Used {0}", memorySize );

        foreach (string str in dirs) {
            getFilesParallel( str );
        }

        mre.WaitOne();
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting output like this:

```
Added 34510 files
Used 301420544
Added 41051 files
Used 313937920
Added 39093 files
Used 322764800
Added 44426 files
Used 342536192
Added 30772 files
Used 350728192
Added 36262 files
Used 360329216
Added 31686 files
Used 368685056
Added 33194 files
Used 374894592
Added 34486 files
Used 384057344
Added 37298 files
Used 393998336
```

This suggests that my code is running sequentially, as I would have expected to find each statement in clumps as they are run on different threads. I've run it several times using different folders, and the result is always the same. Why is this running sequentially?

Comment: Try with some ramdisk software's multiple imaginary disk drives. 6Gb/s is limit i guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have one physical disk drive.  The head of the disk can only be in one place at a time.  That you're asking it for two piece of information at the same time doesn't allow it to actually be in two places at once.

There is some small amount of CPU bound work in your program that can in fact be parallelized, but that is not the main bottleneck.

If you had multiple physical disk drives, and data on each drive, then you could access the data on each in parallel and actually have the work in question be done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Its somewhat difficult to benchmark this accurately, since provided you have enough memory, the first run will cache the data, and subsequent enumerations of the same folder may run without accessing the disk at all.

Its also worth considering that if you have an SSD, it will benefit more from the parallel operations as it supports far more IOPS because it doesn't have any moving parts to wait for.

This code shows that parallel can be up to 2 - 3 times faster on my quad core i5 than single threaded when running against an SSD, or when the data is already cached.

It demonstrates the use of [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.100).aspx), which can take a lot of the pain out of task parallelism.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FilesReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = args[0];
            RunTrial(path, false);
            RunTrial(path, true);
        }

        private static void RunTrial(string path, bool useParallel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel: {0}", useParallel);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            FileListing listing = new FileListing(path, useParallel);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Added {0} files in {1} ms ({2} file/second)", 
                listing.Files.Count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, 
                (listing.Files.Count * 1000 / stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }
    }

    class FileListing
    {
        private ConcurrentList<string> _files;
        private bool _parallelExecution;

        public FileListing(string path, bool parallelExecution)
        {
            _parallelExecution = parallelExecution;
            _files = new ConcurrentList<string>();
            BuildListing(path);
        }

        public ConcurrentList<string> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
        }

        private void BuildListing(string path)
        {
            string[] dirs = null;
            string[] files = null;
            bool success = false;

            try
            {
                dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                success = true;
            }
            catch (SystemException) { /* Suppress security exceptions etc*/ }

            if (success)
            {
                Files.AddRange(files);

                if (_parallelExecution)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(dirs, d => BuildListing(d));
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    {
                        BuildListing(dir);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ConcurrentList<T>
    {
        object lockObject = new object();
        List<T> list;

        public ConcurrentList()
        {
            list = new List<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            lock (lockObject) list.Add(item);

        }
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            lock (lockObject) list.AddRange(collection);
        }

        public long Count
        {
            get { lock (lockObject) return list.Count; }
        }
    }
}
```

I considered using the Concurrent collections instead of rolling a thread safe list implementation, but they proved to be around 5% slower.